# Why won't UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckMark Go Away?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

Okay so I am slowly figuring this out. Just one more issue I am having. I am using a string and saying that if the string is equal to the cell text to put a checkmark on it when it loads the tableView.

Here is my code for that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:transferData]) {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}
```

I am then telling it to remove that checkmark and add the checkmarks accordingly when being selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

  UITableViewCell      *cellCheck = [tableView
                              cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

  transferData = cellCheck.textLabel.text;
  NSLog(@"%@", transferData);
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
```

Everything works fine, except when it first loads. For some reason when I select on another cell, the checkmark that is originally loaded with the tableView won't go away. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a common mistake.

When selecting the cell, you are setting the state of the check mark directly. What you should be doing is setting the state of the checkmark in the data source and let the table cell configure itself from the data source.

**Edited example for an exclusive checked table view**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *changedIndexPaths = nil;

    NSIndexPath *currentCheckedIndexPath = [self indexPathOfCurrentCheckedObject];

    if (currentCheckedIndexPath && ![currentCheckedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        // There is currently a checked index path - unselect the data source and
        // add it to the changed index array.

        [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:currentCheckedIndexPath.row] setChecked:NO];
        changedIndexPaths = @[indexPath, currentCheckedIndexPath];
    } else{
        changedIndexPaths = @[indexPath];
    }

    [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setChecked:YES];

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:changedIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

I have a new [sample app](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/ExclusiveCheckedTableView.zip) you can download to see the whole project:

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. This seems very clear to me but looks very complicated. I ran the sample project and it does exactly what I want except that I want there to be only one checkmark at a time rather then multiple checkmarks at once. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yep. Add some extra checks to find the data object that is currently selected and unset it when you are setting a checkmark to a different object. You should probably change your data model to make this easier. It also seems a bit more complicated because my data objects are dictionaries - if you have custom objects it's just a matter of setting a property - which makes it a bit simpler.

Comment: Sorry. Obviously you know a ton more about this then I do. Trying to imagine in my head how to do this with my code but can't picture it.

Comment: @Zack I've updated my answer and I have a new example app. It's rough and ready - but my excuse is that it's almost 3am for me.

Comment: @Abizem thank you so much for the help. This code is way better for the app since it sounds like the right way to do it. I hate to ask you this, but the only problem I am having left with it is trying to get the array with the titles different then the titles in a loop. Is it possible you could modify the code a little bit more for me just so I can get around this confusion? Thank you so much though!

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
if (self.selectedPath && [indexPath isEqual:self.selectedPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Cells get reused. If you conditionally set any cell attribute, you must always have the 'else' part to reset the attribute.

Edit: With the above change in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, do the following in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath *oldSelection = self.selectedPath;
    if (self.selectedPath) {
        UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedPath];
        uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        self.selectedPath = nil;
    }

    if (oldSelection == nil || ![indexPath isEqual:oldSelection]) {
        UITableViewCell* checkCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        checkCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        self.selectedPath = indexPath;
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

And get rid of the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

And of course you need the `selectedPath` property of type `NSIndexPath *`.

This code lets you pick 0 or 1 row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However for some reason the checkmark is still there!

Comment: The answer you got in the other thread (the code you posted here) isn't really the right answer. This code assumes the row that is checked is also selected. It's not. When your view first loads, no row is selected. So when you select a row for the first time, it gets selected and checked but no row is deselected so nothing gets unchecked. Your code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` should get the currently checked cell and set its accessoryType to None like you had in your original code.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the state directly in the cell - you should be doing it in the datasource. MVC.

Comment: Alright let me try modifying it again back to the original care to go into chat about it @rmaddy?

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? The code I posted still needs to be done regardless of all the other issues.

Comment: @rmaddy I never upvoted you or downvoted you in the first place.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for your updated info, this is great except what is oldSelected? did you mean oldSelection?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo - it just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: This does work except for now there is no checkmark when view is loaded and if I click on one cell the checkmark stays but if I click on another they both stay.

Comment: You need to initialize self.selectedPath with whatever initial row you want selected, if any. There is also one other typo - sorry. It's fixed now. The wrong path was used to get the cell that should be unselected.

Comment: I still take issue with updating the state of the cell directly rather than reloading it from the data source.

Comment: @Abizern How is it any different than updating the state of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: In your simple case, where the checked index is stored separately in the controllor, rather than in the data source objects - very little. But if you have a more complex cell, such as one where it loads a different image, or changes the background colour depending on the checked state, you'll be doing it all yourself, rather than letting the cell load it itself. IMHO, it promotes de-coupling when the cell updates itself in one place.